# Operador '&' em condicional

Tags: php, dart

Me deparei com a sequinte condicional: `if ( ( $resultado <<= 1 ) & 0x10000 )`.
Qual a função do &?
Pois preciso implantar isso em Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão & em uma linguagem de programação como PHP é o operador "AND" a nível de bit. Quando usado em conjunto com dois números, ele realiza uma operação de "AND" bit a bit entre os números.

```php
if (($resultado <<= 1) & 0x10000)
```

Isso está fazendo o seguinte:

`$resultado <<= 1`: Isso desloca o valor de `$resultado` para a esquerda em uma posição. Isso é equivalente a multiplicar `$resultado` por 2. O valor deslocado é armazenado de volta em $resultado.

`& 0x10000`: Isso realiza uma operação de "AND" bit a bit entre o resultado do deslocamento à esquerda e o valor hexadecimal `0x10000` (que é 65536 em decimal).

Comment: Ótima explicação Caio! eu preciso implantar em dart, agora já sei sua função, Obrigado mestre.